# How to remove page number on first index page

Tags: page-numbering, indexing

How to remove page number in the bottom of the first index page?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper, total={2in, 3in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=truexindy, columns=1]

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\index{a}\index{b}\index{c}\index{d}\index{e}\index{f}
\index{g}\index{h}\index{e}\index{k}\index{l}\index{m}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper, total={2in, 3in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=truexindy, columns=1]


\indexsetup{firstpagestyle=empty}%%added now
\begin{document}
```